# How to open second instance of program with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, hotkeys, windows-media-player, media-player, multiple-instances

I used to remember how to do this, use some sort of hotkey to open a second instance of a program that doesn't support it, for example windows media player 12. I have tried WIN+Shift+(number) to open it, but it just brings it to the front. I have accomplished this before, I can remember doing it. I want to listen to music while watching a video clip. I don't want to install the patch, or media player classic, because I know it is possible because I have done this very recently, I just cant remember how. Does anyone know the hotkey? Thank you.

Comment: You didn't accomplish getting WMP to open additional instances just by holding certain keys... WMP tries very heard to NOT allow multiple instances.  See: http://superuser.com/questions/56753/run-multiple-instances-of-windows-media-player. There is no generic hotkey like you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely a hotkey, but hold the Shift key and click the app in the taskbar.

Comment: Just a heads-up: Windows Media Player doesn't seem to allow multiple instances.